# Empty function changes array

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code is doing so weird things and I can't figure out why. First of all it changes list without any code that tells him to do so, second thing it changes every duplicate in the list when it is supposed to change only one. Let me try to explain the problem as best as I can.

Code shown below is supposed to add edit and remove items from the array and update html on the page. Adding and removing items and updating html works fine but removing is wierd.

index.js

```
import UnitsForm from "./lib/UnitsForm.js";

const unitsForm = new UnitsForm();
unitsForm.init();
```

UnitsForm.js

```
import AddEditUnitForm from "./AddEditUnitForm.js";

class UnitsForm {
    formAreaWrap;
    formArea;

    previousForm;
    form;
    nextForm;
    formAfter;

    previousCard;
    card;

    list = [];

    table;

    unitName;

    duplicateButton;
    editButton;
    removeButton;

    nextButton;
    backButton;
    addNewButton;

    addEditUnitForm;

    onSubmit() { }

    constructor() {
        this.formAreaWrap = document.querySelector(".form-area-wrap");
        this.formArea = document.querySelector(".form-area");

        this.previousForm = document.querySelector(".form-2");
        this.form = document.querySelector(".form-3");
        this.nextForm = document.querySelector(".form-4");
        this.formAfter = document.querySelector(".form-5");

        this.previousCard = document.getElementById("businesscard");
        this.card = document.getElementById("unitscard");

        this.table = document.getElementById("unitstable");

        this.nextButton = document.getElementById("unext");
        this.backButton = document.getElementById("uback");
        this.addNewButton = document.getElementById("unew");
    }

    init() {
        this.unitName = document.querySelectorAll(".unit-name")

        this.duplicateButton = document.querySelectorAll(".duplicate");
        this.editButton = document.querySelectorAll(".edit");
        this.removeButton = document.querySelectorAll(".remove");

        this.card.classList.remove("unfocused");
        this.card.classList.add("focused");

        this.duplicateButton.forEach((element, index) => element.onclick = () => this.duplicateHandler(element, index));
        this.editButton.forEach((element, index) => element.onclick = () => this.editHandler(index));
        this.removeButton.forEach((element, index) => element.onclick = () => this.removeHandler(element, index));

        this.nextButton.onclick = this.nextHandler.bind(this);
        this.backButton.onclick = this.backHandler.bind(this);
        this.addNewButton.onclick = this.addNewHandler.bind(this);
    }

    duplicateHandler(element, index) {
        const el = element.parentNode.parentNode;
        el.parentNode.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));

        this.list.push(this.list[index]);

        this.init();
    }

    editHandler(index) {
        this.addEditUnitForm = new AddEditUnitForm(this.list[index], this, index);

        this.form.style.transform = "translateY(-150%)";
        this.formArea.style.height = this.nextForm.offsetHeight + "px";
        this.nextForm.style.transform = "translateY(0)";
    }

    removeHandler(element, index) {
        const el = element.parentNode.parentNode;

        this.list.splice(index, 1);

        el.remove();

        this.init();
    }

    nextHandler() {
        this.form.style.transform = "translateX(-110%)";
        this.formArea.style.height = this.formAfter.offsetHeight + "px";
        this.formAfter.style.transform = "translateX(0)";

        this.onSubmit();
    }

    backHandler() {
        this.card.classList.remove("focused");
        this.card.classList.add("unfocused");

        this.previousCard.classList.remove("valid");
        this.previousCard.classList.add("focused");

        this.form.style.transform = "translateX(110%)";
        this.formArea.style.height = this.previousForm.offsetHeight + "px";
        this.previousForm.style.transform = "translateY(0)";
    }

    addNewHandler() {
        this.addEditUnitForm = new AddEditUnitForm(null, this, null);

        this.form.style.transform = "translateY(-150%)";
        this.formArea.style.height = this.nextForm.offsetHeight + "px";
        this.nextForm.style.transform = "translateY(0)";
    }

    addUnit(values, element) {
        this.table.append(element);

        this.list.push(values);

        this.init();
    }

    editUnit(values, index) { }

    log() {
        this.list.forEach((value) => console.table(value));
    }
}

export default UnitsForm;
```

AddEditUnitForm.js

```
class AddEditUnitForm {
    formAreaWrap;
    formArea;

    previousForm;
    form;

    values;
    index;

    unitNameInput;
    shortNameInput;
    unitTypeInput;
    numberOfUnitsInput;
    standardPriceInput;
    guestsNumberInput;
    areaInput;
    numberOfBathroomInput;
    selectAmenitiesInput;
    pricePerPersonCheckbox;
    descriptionTextarea;
    images = [];

    cancelButton;
    submitButton;

    unitsForm;

    onSubmit() { }

    constructor(...args) {
        this.values = args[0] === null ? {} : args[0];
        this.unitsForm = args[1];
        this.index = args[2];

        this.formAreaWrap = document.querySelector(".form-area-wrap");
        this.formArea = document.querySelector(".form-area");

        this.previousForm = document.querySelector(".form-3");
        this.form = document.querySelector(".form-4");

        this.unitNameInput = document.getElementById("uname");
        this.shortNameInput = document.getElementById("sname");
        this.unitTypeInput = document.getElementById("utype");
        this.numberOfUnitsInput = document.getElementById("noou");
        this.standardPriceInput = document.getElementById("sprice");
        this.guestsNumberInput = document.getElementById("gno");
        this.areaInput = document.getElementById("area");
        this.numberOfBathroomInput = document.getElementById("noob");
        this.selectAmenitiesInput = document.getElementById("sela");
        this.pricePerPersonCheckbox = document.getElementById("ppp");
        this.descriptionTextarea = document.getElementById("desc");

        if (this.index != null) {
            this.unitNameInput.value = this.values["unit-name"];
            this.shortNameInput.value = this.values["short-name"];
            this.unitTypeInput.value = this.values["unit-type"];
            this.numberOfUnitsInput.value = this.values["number-of-units"];
            this.standardPriceInput.value = this.values["standard-price"];
            this.guestsNumberInput.value = this.values["guests-number"];
            this.areaInput.value = this.values["area"];
            this.numberOfBathroomInput.value = this.values["number-of-bathrooms"];
            this.selectAmenitiesInput.value = this.values["select-amenities"];
            this.pricePerPersonCheckbox.checked = this.values["price-per-person"];
            this.descriptionTextarea.value = this.values["description"];
            this.images = this.values["images"];
        }

        this.cancelButton = document.getElementById("aecancel");
        this.submitButton = document.getElementById("aesubmit");

        this.cancelButton.onclick = this.cancelHandler.bind(this);
        this.submitButton.onclick = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
    }

    submitHandler() {
        if (this.index != null) {
            this.values["unit-name"] = this.unitNameInput.value;
            this.values["short-name"] = this.shortNameInput.value;
            this.values["unit-type"] = this.unitTypeInput.value;
            this.values["number-of-units"] = this.numberOfUnitsInput.value;
            this.values["standard-price"] = this.standardPriceInput.value;
            this.values["guests-number"] = this.guestsNumberInput.value;
            this.values["area"] = this.areaInput.value;
            this.values["number-of-bathrooms"] = this.numberOfBathroomInput.value;
            this.values["select-amenities"] = this.selectAmenitiesInput.value;
            this.values["price-per-person"] = this.pricePerPersonCheckbox.checked;
            this.values["description"] = this.descriptionTextarea.value;
            this.values["images"] = this.images;

            this.unitsForm.editUnit(this.values, this.index);
        }
        else {
            this.values["unit-name"] = this.unitNameInput.value;
            this.values["short-name"] = this.shortNameInput.value;
            this.values["unit-type"] = this.unitTypeInput.value;
            this.values["number-of-units"] = this.numberOfUnitsInput.value;
            this.values["standard-price"] = this.standardPriceInput.value;
            this.values["guests-number"] = this.guestsNumberInput.value;
            this.values["area"] = this.areaInput.value;
            this.values["number-of-bathrooms"] = this.numberOfBathroomInput.value;
            this.values["select-amenities"] = this.selectAmenitiesInput.value;
            this.values["price-per-person"] = this.pricePerPersonCheckbox.checked;
            this.values["description"] = this.descriptionTextarea.value;
            this.values["images"] = this.images;

            const element = document.createElement("tr");
            element.innerHTML = `
            <th class="unit-name">${this.values["unit-name"]}</th>
            <th>
                <button class="duplicate">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                        version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 488.3 488.3"
                        style="enable-background:new 0 0 488.3 488.3;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <g>
                            <g>
                                <path
                                    d="M314.25,85.4h-227c-21.3,0-38.6,17.3-38.6,38.6v325.7c0,21.3,17.3,38.6,38.6,38.6h227c21.3,0,38.6-17.3,38.6-38.6V124    C352.75,102.7,335.45,85.4,314.25,85.4z M325.75,449.6c0,6.4-5.2,11.6-11.6,11.6h-227c-6.4,0-11.6-5.2-11.6-11.6V124    c0-6.4,5.2-11.6,11.6-11.6h227c6.4,0,11.6,5.2,11.6,11.6V449.6z" />
                                <path
                                    d="M401.05,0h-227c-21.3,0-38.6,17.3-38.6,38.6c0,7.5,6,13.5,13.5,13.5s13.5-6,13.5-13.5c0-6.4,5.2-11.6,11.6-11.6h227    c6.4,0,11.6,5.2,11.6,11.6v325.7c0,6.4-5.2,11.6-11.6,11.6c-7.5,0-13.5,6-13.5,13.5s6,13.5,13.5,13.5c21.3,0,38.6-17.3,38.6-38.6    V38.6C439.65,17.3,422.35,0,401.05,0z" />
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </th>
            <th>
                <button class="edit">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="492pt" viewBox="0 0 492.49284 492"
                        width="492pt">
                        <path
                            d="m304.140625 82.472656-270.976563 270.996094c-1.363281 1.367188-2.347656 3.09375-2.816406 4.949219l-30.035156 120.554687c-.898438 3.628906.167969 7.488282 2.816406 10.136719 2.003906 2.003906 4.734375 3.113281 7.527344 3.113281.855469 0 1.730469-.105468 2.582031-.320312l120.554688-30.039063c1.878906-.46875 3.585937-1.449219 4.949219-2.8125l271-270.976562zm0 0" />
                        <path
                            d="m476.875 45.523438-30.164062-30.164063c-20.160157-20.160156-55.296876-20.140625-75.433594 0l-36.949219 36.949219 105.597656 105.597656 36.949219-36.949219c10.070312-10.066406 15.617188-23.464843 15.617188-37.714843s-5.546876-27.648438-15.617188-37.71875zm0 0" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </th>
            <th>
                <button class="remove">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="427pt" viewBox="-40 0 427 427.00131"
                        width="427pt">
                        <path
                            d="m232.398438 154.703125c-5.523438 0-10 4.476563-10 10v189c0 5.519531 4.476562 10 10 10 5.523437 0 10-4.480469 10-10v-189c0-5.523437-4.476563-10-10-10zm0 0" />
                        <path
                            d="m114.398438 154.703125c-5.523438 0-10 4.476563-10 10v189c0 5.519531 4.476562 10 10 10 5.523437 0 10-4.480469 10-10v-189c0-5.523437-4.476563-10-10-10zm0 0" />
                        <path
                            d="m28.398438 127.121094v246.378906c0 14.5625 5.339843 28.238281 14.667968 38.050781 9.285156 9.839844 22.207032 15.425781 35.730469 15.449219h189.203125c13.527344-.023438 26.449219-5.609375 35.730469-15.449219 9.328125-9.8125 14.667969-23.488281 14.667969-38.050781v-246.378906c18.542968-4.921875 30.558593-22.835938 28.078124-41.863282-2.484374-19.023437-18.691406-33.253906-37.878906-33.257812h-51.199218v-12.5c.058593-10.511719-4.097657-20.605469-11.539063-28.03125-7.441406-7.421875-17.550781-11.5546875-28.0625-11.46875h-88.796875c-10.511719-.0859375-20.621094 4.046875-28.0625 11.46875-7.441406 7.425781-11.597656 17.519531-11.539062 28.03125v12.5h-51.199219c-19.1875.003906-35.394531 14.234375-37.878907 33.257812-2.480468 19.027344 9.535157 36.941407 28.078126 41.863282zm239.601562 279.878906h-189.203125c-17.097656 0-30.398437-14.6875-30.398437-33.5v-245.5h250v245.5c0 18.8125-13.300782 33.5-30.398438 33.5zm-158.601562-367.5c-.066407-5.207031 1.980468-10.21875 5.675781-13.894531 3.691406-3.675781 8.714843-5.695313 13.925781-5.605469h88.796875c5.210937-.089844 10.234375 1.929688 13.925781 5.605469 3.695313 3.671875 5.742188 8.6875 5.675782 13.894531v12.5h-128zm-71.199219 32.5h270.398437c9.941406 0 18 8.058594 18 18s-8.058594 18-18 18h-270.398437c-9.941407 0-18-8.058594-18-18s8.058593-18 18-18zm0 0" />
                        <path
                            d="m173.398438 154.703125c-5.523438 0-10 4.476563-10 10v189c0 5.519531 4.476562 10 10 10 5.523437 0 10-4.480469 10-10v-189c0-5.523437-4.476563-10-10-10zm0 0" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </th>`

            this.unitsForm.addUnit(this.values, element)
        }

        this.unitNameInput.value = "";
        this.shortNameInput.value = "";
        this.unitTypeInput.value = "";
        this.numberOfUnitsInput.value = "";
        this.standardPriceInput.value = "";
        this.guestsNumberInput.value = "";
        this.areaInput.value = "";
        this.numberOfBathroomInput.value = "";
        this.selectAmenitiesInput.value = "";
        this.pricePerPersonCheckbox.checked = false;
        this.descriptionTextarea.value = "";
        this.images = [];

        this.form.style.transform = "translateY(150%)";
        this.formArea.style.height = this.previousForm.offsetHeight + "px";
        this.previousForm.style.transform = "translateY(0)";

        this.onSubmit();
    }

    cancelHandler() {
        this.unitNameInput.value = "";
        this.shortNameInput.value = "";
        this.unitTypeInput.value = "";
        this.numberOfUnitsInput.value = "";
        this.standardPriceInput.value = "";
        this.guestsNumberInput.value = "";
        this.areaInput.value = "";
        this.numberOfBathroomInput.value = "";
        this.selectAmenitiesInput.value = "";
        this.pricePerPersonCheckbox.checked = false;
        this.descriptionTextarea.value = "";
        this.images = [];

        this.form.style.transform = "translateY(150%)";
        this.formArea.style.height = this.previousForm.offsetHeight + "px";
        this.previousForm.style.transform = "translateY(0)";
    }
}

export default AddEditUnitForm;
```

First I ran into the problem of `editUnit(values, index)` function changing every item in the list that's added with `duplicateHandler(element, index)`, it was weird because it was supposed to change only one specific item in the array:

```
editUnit(values, index) { 
    this.list[index] = values;
}
```

So I removed the code from the function completely to work on the problem, and I forgot about it because I thought it might be the problem in `duplicateHandler(element, index)` function, made few tweaks and nothing changed. I was then sure it was the problem in `editUnit(values, index)` and came back to it just to realize it was empty, and I was mind blown like why the heck does empty function changes array, it's supposed to do nothing it's empty. I tried clearing cache in browser nothing, tried different browser same thing, tried tweaking AddEditUnitForm.js nothing again. I'm exhausted I spent hours trying to find what's causing the array to change. Every help is much appreciated!

Comment: Comments all the lines that change the array and then uncomment them one by one.

Comment: Either that, or try pinpointing the faulty line by logging your object at the start of every function.

Comment: Already did all of that before asking the question...

Answer (score 0):

Update: I fixed it!

First problem: Function that was changing the array was `submitHandler()` in AddEditUnitForm.js. I was updating the values of item passed through constructor directly.

Second problem: Apparently when you duplicate items in array like this `array.push[array[i]];` they are the same, so when you change one item it changes them all.